# Web scraping a JSON file with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve the timetable from [this site](https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/) using Requests.
I make the post sending the right parameters and get back the empty HTML skeleton, but instead I would like to get the [json file](https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php) returned.

Here is what I see when inspecting the page and highlighted you can see the file I want to retrieve.

[image: inspecting the page]

Here is my code so far:

```
url = "https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/"
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
data = "msg=TimeTable&req=%7B%22getAvailability%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22getBasicPrice%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22getRouteAnalysis%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22directOnly%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22legs%22%3A%224%22%2C%22pax%22%3A1%2C%22origin%22%3A%22BEV%22%2C%22destination%22%3A%22ISC%22%2C%22tripRequest%22%3A%5B%7B%22tripfrom%22%3A%22BEV%22%2C%22tripto%22%3A%22ISC%22%2C%22tripdate%22%3A%222020-03-19%22%2C%22tripleg%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22tripfrom%22%3A%22ISC%22%2C%22tripto%22%3A%22BEV%22%2C%22tripdate%22%3A%222020-03-19%22%2C%22tripleg%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%22tripfrom%22%3A%22BEV%22%2C%22tripto%22%3A%22FOR%22%2C%22tripdate%22%3A%222020-03-19%22%2C%22tripleg%22%3A2%7D%2C%7B%22tripfrom%22%3A%22FOR%22%2C%22tripto%22%3A%22BEV%22%2C%22tripdate%22%3A%222020-03-19%22%2C%22tripleg%22%3A3%7D%5D%7D"
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request should be as below:

```
url = 'https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php'

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}

data = {
  'msg': 'TimeTable',
  'req': '{"getAvailability":"Y","getBasicPrice":"Y","getRouteAnalysis":"Y","directOnly":"Y","legs":1,"pax":1,"origin":"BEV","destination":"FOR","tripRequest":[{"tripfrom":"BEV","tripto":"FOR","tripdate":"2020-03-18","tripleg":0}]}'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is one of the moments I ask myself "why didn't I think of it"

Comment: it works but I'm gettin back no data and error 'Invalid session ID'. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Check cookies for Session ID. You can use `requests.session()` to store cookies between requests

Comment: Thanks. I did give it a go but I'm still getting the error. I've created a new question if you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728735/making-a-post-request-with-session

Comment: It's more complex than send single request using session. You need to analyze website, find how session id is created or if there's any other cookies, tokens required. There can be javascripts that you cannot handle using requests. You can try to make request to the main page first using session and then make yours.

Comment: Thanks Sers. They do use a cookie. I made the request using the cookie from browser inspect and it worked. I've updated the questions to know how I can get the cookie.